# viewing my database in the view at laravel

Tags: php, laravel

sorry if this is a very newbie Q..
but please help me to solve this problem. plus give me the reason about why this error happened..

this is my edit view

new.blade.php

```
@section('content')
@include('common.show_error')

{{Form::open(array('url'=>'author/update', 'method'=>'PUT'))}}

<p>
    {{ Form::label('name', 'Name: ') }}</br>
    {{ Form::text('name', $author->name) }}
</p>

<p>
    {{ Form::label('bio', 'Biography: ') }}</br>
    {{ Form::textarea('bio', $author->bio) }}
</p>

{{ Form::hidden('id', $author->id) }}

<p>{{ Form::submit('Edit Data') }}</p>
```

@stop

this is my show view

show.blade.php

```
@extends('layouts.default')

@section('content')
<h1>{{ $author->name }}</h1>

<p>{{ $author->bio }}</p>

<p>{{ $author->updated_at }}</p>

<span>
    {{ HTML::linkRoute('authors', 'Home') }} |
    {{ HTML::linkRoute('edit_author', 'Edit', array($author->id)) }} |
    {{ Form::open(array('url'=>'author/destroy', 'method'=>'DELETE', 'style'=>'display: inline;')) }}
    {{ Form::hidden('id', $author->id) }}
    {{ Form::submit('Delete') }}
    {{ Form::close() }}
</span>
@stop
```

this is my controller

```
public function update($id)
{
    $id = Input::get('id');

    $validator = Member::validate(Input::all());

    if($validator->fails()){
        return Redirect::route('members.edit', $id)->withErrors($validator);
    } else {
        Member::where('id','=',$id)->update(array(
            'name' => Input::get('name'),
            'bio' => Input::get('bio')
        ));

        return Redirect::route('members.show', $id)
            ->with('message', 'Data Succesfully Updated');
    }
}
```

the case: when I try to edit data using edit button. it said:

"Trying to get property of non-object laravel"

and when I check at the error log. it refers to

```
<h1>{{ $author->name }}</h1>
```

Comment: Wheres the controller or route that displays the show page?? Thats likely where the problem is arising

Comment: Can you post your code for the controller that handles `members.edit` and `members.show` routes?

Answer (score 0):

```
public function update($id)
{
    $id = Input::get('id');

    $validator = Member::validate(Input::all());

    if($validator->fails()){
        return Redirect::route('members.edit', $id)->withErrors($validator);
    } else {
            $author = Member::find($id);
            $author->update(array(
            'name' => Input::get('name'),
            'bio' => Input::get('bio')
        ));

        return Redirect::route('members.show', $id)
            ->with('message', 'Data Succesfully Updated')
            ->with('author', $author);
    }
}
```

Little changes in your controller, try it :) In your code, you are not send variable "author" into your view.